# In Site.com, how do you use browser-prefixes in your CSS?

Tags: css, site.com

I'm creating a button element with a linear-gradient. But some mobile browsers don't yet support the CSS linear-gradient property without browser prefix. Specifically I want to use -webkit-linear-gradient. But whenever I add the browser prefix, Site.com removes the prefix on save, and leaves the property as 'linear-gradient,' without the prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be supported (yet?).  When I first started working with Site.com @media queries weren't supported and got stripped out which sounds eerily similar to what you are observing.

The work around was to put them in a separate file and not import them as CSS assets which had the adverse effect of not allowing us to use the Style Editor.  We then had to manually add the style links in the head on our root page template, so it would be used in all of our pages.

Look at [this answer by @RyanGuest to a similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3827/154).

Comment: Thanks Peter Knolle. I think using the workarounds specified in that answer will work for this too. I don't want the people behind Site.com to think this is a solution, but for now I'll mark this as a solution. Thanks!