# Can't import bootstrap on Site.com as a stylesheet

Tags: community, bootstrap

I'm just starting with communities and would like to know if there is a way of uploading bootstrap.css file onto site.com. When i try to upload a document and convert it to css it comes up with the following error: 
[image]

anyone knows if there is a way around it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I've found is that Site.com doesn't support the CSS selector :not() at the moment which is found in CSS frameworks such as Bootstrap (info on the :not() selector - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not). The following are some links to some workarounds so you can use Bootstrap:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506871/cant-import-bootstrap-css-using-site-com-platform
- [Site.com CSS not recognizing media queries](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/site-com-css-not-recognizing-media-queries/3827#3827)

The only downsides will be that you won't be able to use the Style Editor directly if you go with one of these workarounds.